# URL masking in JHIPSTER

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to create a mapping/masking for my URL pattern like '/abc.bcd.1' to '/page/abc.bcd.1', basically, the user will be shown the URL '/abc.bcd.1' whereas internally the url would be '/page/abc.bcd.1'. This would open the page 'page.html'.

I have tried doing this by adding regex's in the 'staticResourcesProductionFilter' but it is not working. For eg:

```
staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/(*).(*).1");
```

In the above case, the URL is not accepted and control is not forwarded to the doFilter method.

Can't seem to figure this out. Please point me the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "static production filter" only works in production mode, when you use the "prod" Spring profile. That might explain why it didn't work.

To answer you more specifically:

- JHipster is made for "single page Web applications", so this should be just a configuration in your AngularJS router
- From my understanding, you are having a "real" page in that URL : JHipster uses the Thymeleaf template engine for serving server-side pages, have you had a look at it? I guess you could just do that mapping in Thymeleaf

Comment: I was using the prod profile itself. The URL mapping did not work. Also, by single page web application do you mean that we should not use it for multi-page application? Also, I did not check Thymeleaf. I will check it.

Comment: If you use AngularJS, the idea is that you have only 1 Web page. Of course you could have several pages, but that's not the "philosophy" of the thing. For people like you who want to have several pages, we have added the Thymeleaf option, which seems to be a better fit.